# How can i hide a cog from my help command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Sorry for not writing any code but my question is if there a way to hide a cog from my help command.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should indeed share some code/your approaches and the errors you face.

Comment: I don't have any error I'm just asking how can I hide a cog for my help command.........

Comment: And you did not even try something out? Nothing to share?

Comment: i tried adding `command_attrs=dict(hidden=True)` to my code.Now the commands dont show up but the cog still does show up

Answer (score 1):

When you type in `@commands.command()` simply add "hidden=True":

```
@commands.command(hidden=True)
```

and the command will be hidden from the help.